# How to create partition using FieldPartitioner from Kafka S3 Sink Connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am looking for the correct **format** to be applied to `s3-sink.properties` for Kafka S3 Sink Connector, using partition.class [FieldPartitioner](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html#partitioning-records-into-s3-objects). 
I need to create **3 partitions** (one sub-partition of the other, like *field1=value/field2=value/field3=value*) based in Fields names from my kafka message.

I really need an example here for the usage of **partition.field.name**. It receives a **list**, but I couldn't find an example yet.

This is what I have so far and what I needed:

```
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.parquet.ParquetFormat
schema.generator.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator
schema.compatibility=NONE
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.FieldPartitioner
partition.field.name=fieldName #Wrong so far, it can't even find my first one with this format. And I need two more, like: partition.field.name=field1,field2,field3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> It receives a list

It's a CSV list (just like `bootstrap.servers`) of **top-level** field names.

And your data must be a Struct (Avro or JSON with `schema.enabled=true`)

You can find examples in the unit tests - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/v5.3.2/partitioner/src/test/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/partitioner/FieldPartitionerTest.java#L140

Comment: And mentioned before, `connect-distributed` **is preferred**, to run Kafka Connect, so you would **use JSON** instead of properties files to configure connectors